# correct way to update tree node in ng-zorro-antd

Tags: angular, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I'm trying to update node (title) in the tree.
As I understand tree will only reflect changes if nodes array changed by ref (see example), but in this case after I update nodes the tree got noticeable flickering  when redrawing, how do I prevent this,
see stackbliz examale https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2rvj6b-xzwloq, thanks !

Comment: Can't seem to recreate your issue in your stackblitz. I can't see any flickering?

Comment: @Viqas sorry wrong link, correct one https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2rvj6b-xzwloq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nzNoAnimation everywhere, example updated

Comment: But we loose the animations. Is there a way to keep them?